# How to create evenly spaced columns in Foundation with the first one being blank?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to create 3 evenly spaced columns using Foundation. The first column however is to be blank.

So this works..

```
<div class="row panel">
<div class="small-4 columns">
      <br>
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns text-center">
    <img src="images/something.png">
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns text-right">
    <h1>title</h1>
</div>
```

I'm not clear how "end" and "offsets" work. ([docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)) But I'm sure there is a way to make to make this cleaner? i.e. remove the first 'columns div'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Offset` can be used, but `end` cannot be used to get the layout you want.
`end`- in foundation framework Last column in row is floated to right. If you have uncompleted row.you will be left with space in between columns as last column floats to right-This case you use `end` so that the last column stacks next to the previous column by floating to left.

```
<div class="small-4 small-offset-4 columns">
    <img src="images/something.png">
</div>
<div class="small-4 columns text-right">
    <h1>title</h1>
</div>
```

First div tag implies to occupy four columns of space by having an offset of four columns.